# How to redirect urllib2 debug output without globally redefining sys.stderr?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.6

In `urllib2` how can I redirect the output a particular opener generates when I specify the `debuglevel` parameter?

E.g. for this example

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=2))
opener.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

how would I catch the output in an "object" similar to `sys.stderr` and be able to write it anywhere I like?

I have a script that uses logging and `stderr` and this particular output should go to the log without hampering any of the other output.

Comment: note: [the code shows that the output is printed to `sys.stdout`, not `sys.stderr`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/httplib.py#l405).

Comment: are there multiple threads in your program that may  print while urllib2 makes requests?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yep, unfortunately. Thanks for your answer and your time. I guess I'll have to use locking or a separate log file for the `urllib2` debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The debug output is produced using [`print` statements that print to `sys.stdout`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/httplib.py#l405).

It is easy to [redirect `sys.stdout` temporarily for the duration of the `urllib2` request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) but the effects are global i.e., if there are other Python threads are runnings then they'll see the change if they print something to `sys.stdout`.

You probably can't override what `print` statement does in Python 2.6. You can do it in Python 3 where `print()` is a function.

Comment: Would `from __future__ import print_function` fix the limitation you mention?

Comment: no. `__future__`  affects only the current module. It has no effect on `urllib2`